# Deja Dup problem to restore files after system reinstall

Tags: upgrade, deja-dup

After backing up my home directory, I have just reinstalled Ubuntu because of operating problems. I now can't restore my files; should I have not used Deja Dup since the files are encrypted, and the key was lost with the system reinstall?